# Looking for a Compilable Form of DeleteDuplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, function-construction, compile, code-request

### `Union` is Compilable but `DeleteDuplicates` Isn't?!

First, `DeleteDuplicates` is not compilable in that it does not appear in the list `` Compile`CompilerFunctions[] `` and it calls `MainEvaluate` in `Compile`. What is strange is that `Union` is compilable in this sense (appears on the list). `Union` does what `DeleteDuplicates` does and more.

The documentation center mentions `DeleteDuplicates` is "substantially" faster.

- "DeleteDuplicates is similar to Union without sorting:... Avoiding the sort improves the speed substantially:"

Does anyone know why `Union` is compilable but the more basic `DeleteDuplicates` isn't?

---

### Compilable Form of `DeleteDuplicates`

Secondly and more importantly, calling `DeleteDuplicates` in `Compile` with `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` as well as `Parallelization -> True` is even more detrimental as an error is often thrown. The following is an example.

```
comp = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 2}, {c, _Integer}},
  DeleteDuplicates[list],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
(*no error*)

list = {{4, 4}, {5, 5}, {3, 3}, {6, 6}};
c = 4;

comp[list, c]
(*no error*)

comp[list, {c, 1}]
(*throws error*)
```

The error thrown is below. The stuff inside `CompiledFunction` looks strange.

[image: error message]

Replacing `DeleteDuplicates` with `Union` results in no error and everything goes well. However, `Union` is overkill, as it does extraneous work.

I am looking for a compilable form of `DeleteDuplicates` that does not call `MainEvaluate` and is optimized in memory and speed. In particular, it should beat the same code with `Union` in its place. It should work with the settings `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` and `Parallelization -> True`. Any ideas?

(If it matters, the particular context I am looking at is deleting duplicates in a list of pairs of integers greater than or equal to 0 and less than 204, as with `list` in my example above.)

Comment: Do the integers you talk about have a pre-specified, not too large range? Are they always greater than `0`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher In my specific case, all integers are greater than or equal to 0. I may be able to fidget things so that they are strictly greater than 0. Yes to your other question. They are all smaller than a known, relatively small, specifiable number as well.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your other answer is for a compilable form of `DeleteCases`. I am looking for a compilable form of `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7):

We can build a primitive hash table to determine if an element has been seen.

First we key on the first element of each pair, then over the second element. We use a 2D integer array, where each values is stored with a single bit.

For your example our lookup array has dimensions $205 \times 4$ on a 64 bit machine.

```
With[{len = $SystemWordLength - 1},
deleteIntegerPairDuplicates = 
  Compile[{{lis, _Integer, 2}, {min, _Integer}, {max, _Integer}},
    Module[{rng, tbl1, present, bag, quos, locs, val, v1, v2, pos1, pos2, bits, loc},
      rng = max - min + 1;
      tbl1 = Table[0, {Quotient[rng, len] + 1}];
      present = Table[tbl1, {max - min + 1}];
      bag = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]];
      
      (* precompute quotients and mods since 
          BitShiftRight and BitSet are not compilable! *)
      quos = Quotient[Range[rng], len] + 1;
      locs = 2^Subtract[Range[rng], len*Subtract[quos, 1]];

      Do[
        val = Compile`GetElement[lis, i];
        v1 = Compile`GetElement[val, 1];
        v2 = Compile`GetElement[val, 2];
        
        pos1 = v1 + min + 1;
        pos2 = Compile`GetElement[quos, v2 + min + 1];
        
        bits = present[[pos1, pos2]];
        loc = Compile`GetElement[locs, v2 + min + 1];
        
        If[BitAnd[bits, loc] === 0,
          Internal`StuffBag[bag, v1];
          Internal`StuffBag[bag, v2];
          present[[pos1, pos2]] = BitOr[bits, loc];
        ],
        {i, Length[lis]}
      ];
      
      Partition[Internal`BagPart[bag, All], 2]
    ],
    CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True},
    CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ];
]
```

You can bake this into your other compiled routine through this option:

```
CompilationOptions -> {
  "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True,
  "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True
}
```

For the range $0$ to $204$, this routines seem on par with `DeleteDuplicates` and is noticeably faster than `Union`. Some benchmarks:

```
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomChoice[Range[0, 204], {10^6, 2}];

res1 = deleteIntegerPairDuplicates[list, 0, 204]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0341, Null}
> ```

```
res2 = DeleteDuplicates[list]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.04, Null}
> ```

```
res3 = Union[list]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.2, Null}
> ```

```
 res1 === res2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Sort[res1] === res3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: There seems to be a case where your function doesn't work but `DeleteDuplicates` does. The code ```comp = Compile[{{n,_Integer},{listOfInts,_Integer,1},{listOfPairs, _Integer,2}},deleteIntegerPairDuplicates[Join[listOfPairs,{{1, 1}}],0,n],Parallelization ->True, CompilationTarget->"C",CompilationOptions->{"InlineCompiledFunctions" ->True}];``` gives the error ```CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary ... error: use of undeclared identifier 'P1'```. However, replacing `deleteIntegerPairDuplicates` with `DeleteDuplicates` or simply removing `CompilationTarget -> "C"` (which I need) produces no error.

Comment: Ah, see my latest edit. We need another option in `CompilationOptions` setting.

Comment: I also just changed `len = $SystemWordLength` to `len = $SystemWordLength - 1`. If `len = $SystemWordLength` and the outer `Compile` call isn't using `RuntimeOptions` -> "Speed", we get a failure due to machine overflow.

Answer (score 6):

*Not an answer at all, but too long for a comment.*

In your very particular use case, `SparseArray` can delete the duplicates a bit faster:

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10000000, 2}];
aa = DeleteDuplicates[list]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
bb = SparseArray[list -> 1.]["NonzeroPositions"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Sort[aa] == Sort[bb]
```

> 0.271432
>
> 0.186625
>
> True

Comment: Clever! I am hoping for a compilable form of `DeleteDuplicates`, and `SparseArray` is not compilable. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, I know that it isn't compilable. I just could not hesitate to post this. Abusing `SparseArray`s is some sort of sport on this site. You're welcome nonetheless. ;)